# sas infile dataline trunctuates at 8 characters

Tags: sas, truncate

Having not worked with SAS for a couple of years, i am trying to get back into it...

I am trying to read data with comma-delimited datalines. While there are plenty of examples, I can't quite get the following to import my data correctly:

```
data h0;
   infile datalines delimiter=','; 
   input
   kst
   kst_bez $
   hx $
   hx_bez $
   hxx $
   hxx_bez $
   hxxx $
   hxxx_bez $
;
   datalines;
10000,Team 1 South,H0,Group,H10,Retail,H112,Retail Germany
10001,Team 2 North & West,H0,H10,Retail Division 2,H112,Retail Germany
10003,Human Res,H0,Group,H20,HR,H112,HR Germany
;
```

I would have thought that `delimiter=','` tells SAS to simply read the data between my `,`-Characters into something like a `VARCHAR`-variable... however, any alphanumeric data is truncated at 8 characters.

I vaguely remember I have to use something like `$varying40.`, which is in line with the examples I found - however, if I add this to my variables, the variable doesn't stop at the `,`, but instead reads the whole, say, 40 characters.

Any hints?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't define them otherwise SAS will default all characters variables to length 8.  It is probably clearer for you and the SAS compiler if you explicitly define the variables using a `LENGTH` or `ATTRIB` statement before using them.  Otherwise SAS has to guess at how you wanted them defined based on how they are first used.

```
data h0;
  length kst 8 kst_bez $20 hx $20 hx_bez $20 hxx $20 hxx_bez $20 
         hxxx $20 hxxx_bez $20
  ;
  infile datalines dsd truncover ;
  input kst -- hxxx_bez ;
datalines;
...
```

You could add in-line informat specifications to the INPUT statement as the first use of the variable and SAS will default to the width of the informat used, but make sure to add the colon prefix to prevent SAS from reading past the delimiters.

```
data h0;
  infile datalines dsd truncover ;
  input kst kst_bez :$20. hx :$20. hx_bez :$20. hxx :$20. hxx_bez :$20. 
        hxxx :$20. hxxx_bez :$20.
  ;
datalines;
...
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Both options work like a charm. When to use which is a mystery at this point, but I guess I figure it out once I get back into SAS! `truncover` was the part that I clearly missed.